# .ReplaceWith() not replacing XElement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Within an xml document I have the following

```
  ...  
    <TablixMembers>
       <TablixMember>
          <Group Name="Details" />
       </TablixMember>
     </TablixMembers>
   </TablixMember>
     <TablixHeader Name="MyField3" />
     <TablixHeader Name="MyField2" /> 
 </TablixMembers>
</TablixMember>
```

I have a for loop that looks for each element with a field name ("MyField3, MyField2, ...)

```
for (int g = 0; g < remainingtotals; g++)
{
   groupTotals.Reverse();
   ff.Add(new XElement(ns + "TablixHeader"));
   ff.Descendants(ns + "TablixHeader").Last().SetAttributeValue("Name", groupTotals[g]);

   string nName = GenerateUniqueName("Nsted");
   while (ff.Descendants(ns + "TablixHeader").Any(n => (string)n.Attribute("Name") == groupTotals[g]))
   {
     var newnode = ff.Descendants(ns + "TablixHeader").Where(n => (string)n.Attribute("Name") == groupTotals[g]).Single();
     newnode.ReplaceWith(new XElement(tGroupHeader));
   }

groupTotals.Reverse();
}
```

Within this loop I have a `List<string> groupTotals` which holds the names of the fields.
It may not need to be in a `while` loop (I added this for testing) I have a query that looks for the specific field

```
var newnode = ff.Descendants(ns + "TablixHeader").Where(n => (string)n.Attribute("Name") == groupTotals[g]).Single();
         newnode.ReplaceWith(new XElement(tGroupHeader));
```

This sets newnode equal to:

```
<TablixHeader Name="MyField3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" />
```

On the next line I am trying to replace this node with a new xml element structure

```
newnode.ReplaceWith(new XElement(tGroupHeader));
```

tGroupHeader is a memorystream that contains a large xml Element template that should be inserted and replace the current tablix node of the selected attribute name.

When this code runs the node does not get replaced. In fact nothing happens, I've set break points on the node, no xml exception is thrown it just steps right through it. I assume I am either calling the method incorrectly or the selecting of a single node is what is causing it to not replace the element.

I also thought it may be due to the injection of a large xml structure but I have also tested this using just a single element such as:

```
newnode.ReplaceWith(new XElement(ns + "Size"));// ns is the xml namespace for the schema I am using
```

this also did not result in the element being replaced.

Can anyone provide some insight into what I may be doing wrong?

-cheers

Comment: Better safe then sorry: are you calling `XDocument.Save()` after you modify the document?

Comment: The document is rendered/created it's just that using ReplaceWith is not replacing the current node with new xml

Comment: did you fix this, I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a work around for this it may not be the best approach but it was reliable. From what I could see when I attempted to query the node the element would be located but it would not update I think this was due in part to my attempt to inject and update based upon a `.Descendants()` query all within one method (this may not be right but it was all I could determine).

The work around approach that I used was instead of trying to navigate the xml structure for an element at the time of creating the element I added an ID attribute with a specific name.

```
ff.Add(new XElement(ns + "TablixMember"));
ff.Descendants(ns + "TablixMember").Last().SetAttributeValue("Name", groupTotals[g]);
ff.Descendants(ns + "TablixMember").Last().SetAttributeValue("ID", groupedItemTotals[g].GroupPosition.ToString());
```

This would then insert an XElement such as

```
   <TablixMembers>
      <TablixMember>
        <TablixHeader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
         <Size>1in</Size>
            <CellContents>
              <Textbox Name="GroupTotalPPPccc2973356bf4beaa92cb0409b37b8ef" ID="1">
                   <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                       <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
<--end snip -->
```

Once I added the id it made querying for the node much simpler

```
  var newnode = ff.Descendants(ns + "TablixMember").Where(n => (string)n.Attribute("ID") == groupedItemTotals[g].GroupPosition.ToString()).Single();
```

From here I could then updated the elements within the node using Replace(). ReplaceWith() SetAttribut() etc.

in this snippet I selected the node, removed all child elements and then injected a new structure

```
newnode.RemoveAll();
newnode.Add(new XElement(tGroupHeader),
new XElement(ns + "KeepWithGroup"));
newnode.Descendants(ns + "TablixHeader").Last().Descendants(ns + "Textbox").Last().SetAttributeValue("Name", nName);
```

Finally, since the ID attribute was not supported by the current schema I was using I performed some clean up to remove any unsupported attributes.

```
report.Descendants(ns + "TablixMember").Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("ID") != null).Attributes("ID").Remove();
report.Descendants(ns + "Textbox").Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("ID") != null).Attributes("ID").Remove();
```

I'd be interested to see other suggestions or ideas.

thanks